# CSS - renaming fonts

Tags: css, fonts

A fellow programmer has built a page with webfonts, but didn't provide any fallbacks in the font-family rules for where they added this to the appropriate html elements.

for example:

```
#someDiv { font-family: "my font"; }
```

In some special cases, we're not loading the webfont, and it looks pretty ugly. The font should fall back on Arial.
Instead of going over the CSS line-by-line and fix this, is there a way to add a font-face rule or something similar so that "my font" will show Arial?

Comment: You can give `Arial` to body.

Comment: no you cannot. Since you issue a new `font-family` rule for that div it will overwrite the previous one. If the font does not exist it will not inherit from another rule. It will use the browsers default.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "my font";
    src: local("Arial");
}
```

Comment: This example will replace your currently defined font family "my font" to use Arial when "my font" is used as the font family name. This isn't a fallback. It's replacing your custom font with Arial.

Answer (score -2):

Add your fallbacks to the current font-family chain.

```
#someDiv { font-family: "my font", Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, since I will have to go over dozens of lines and fix it manually.

Comment: have you checked the `@font-face` declaration, does it contain all the required font types? `.eot`, `.woff`', `.woff2` , `.ttf`, `.svg` All of these formats are required to play nicely with all browser types.

Comment: The font-face declaration is fine. The problem is when I intentionally remove the font-face declaration (it is done in some cases because of performance issues). I want the font to revert to Arial.

Comment: then you will have to chain the family! use find and replace.

Comment: It really shouldn't take that long with find --> replace.